# How to handle unsupported attribute in Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-github

I have a terraform code as given below

```
   locals {
    file_path = format("%s-%s", var.test1, var.test2)
    test_decode  =  yamldecode((data.github_repository_file.test.content))
   }
    data "github_repository_file" "test" {
     repository = "test-repo"
     branch     = "develop"
    file       = "${local.file_path}/local/test.yaml"
    }
  test_encode = ${yamlencode(local.test_decode.spec.names)}
```

This is working fine when a "**.spec.names**" attribute present in the test.yaml file. Since we are selecting the test.yaml based on local.file_path some times attribute .spec.names might not present in the test.yaml and the plan failing with  **"Error: Unsupported attribute"**. How to check "**.spec.names**" attribute  present in the test.yaml?

Updating the question to add yaml example

**Yaml with names attribute**

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.gitops.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: "test"
  namespace: "test-system"
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: "test-environment"
      version: "0.1.10"
  names:
    key1: "value1"
    key2: "value2"
    key3: "value3"
    key4: "value4"
```

**YAML without names attribute**

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.gitops.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: "test"
  namespace: "test-system"
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: "test-environment"
      version: "0.1.10"
```

Comment: Can you provide actual example of the yaml file with and without your attributes?

Comment: @Marcin I updated the question by adding the YAML file example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [try](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try):

```
  test_encode = yamlencode(try(local.test_decode.spec.names, "some_default_value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a more elegant way exists, but you can check if a property exists like this:

```
contains([for k, v in local.test_decode : k], "spec")
```

chaining this to check if the spec and the names exists like this did **not** work for me as the second condition was still evaluated even if the first condition failed:

```
contains([for k, v in local.test_decode : k], "spec") && contains([for k, v in local.test_decode.spec : k], "names")
```

this does the trick, but I don't like it, because I consider it to be quite hacky:

```
contains([for k, v in local.test_decode : k], "spec") ? contains([for k, v in local.test_decode.spec : k], "names") : false
```